# How to return a value from nested javascript function?

Tags: javascript

```
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), noop = function(){};      
pc.createDataChannel("");   
pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);        
pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
  if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;
  ice.candidate.candidate.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {   
    if (line.indexOf("candidate")!==-1) {           
      var parts = line.split(' '),             
      addr = parts[4],
      type = parts[7];
      if (type === 'host') {
        console.log(addr);
        return addr;
      }
    } 
  });
  pc.onicecandidate = noop;
};
```

In the above javascript, the console.log(addr) works but not the return. Please point me where I am doing wrong. I tried to wrap this in a function and that doesn't work it either.

Comment: `return addr;` will return from the `.forEach` callback but that doesn't do anything at all - the `.forEach` just continues with the next thing. Use a normal loop or perhaps `.find()` - note that `.find()` doesn't transform the value, it just returns the item from the array where the callback returned a truthy value.

Comment: This might help with how to think about callbacks/"nested" functions: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: You could just use `for (const line of ice.candidate.candidate.split('\r\n')) { ... }` instead of `forEach` to make your code work.

Comment: Thanks @felixKling, the link definitely helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
  if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

  const hosts = [];

  ice.candidate.candidate.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {   
    if (line.indexOf("candidate")!==-1) {           
      var parts = line.split(' '),             
      addr = parts[4],
      type = parts[7];
      if (type === 'host') {
        console.log(addr);

        hosts.push(addr)

      }
    }
  });
  pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  
  return hosts;
};
```

Is something like that what you are after?

You want to return each host address?

This stores the hosts locally. Foreach is synchronous so when it has completed working on the collection then your function will reach the return statement.

If you want to find the first address then you might want to use .find instead of .forEach, or check that a value exists and bail from the forEach when it does (note that you're still calling that function on each item, it'll just return straight away). You *can* break out of a forEach but its not idiomatic, you'd have to throw an exception and you try..catch, a bit nasty in JS and not really the intended use for the syntax.

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
  if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

  const line = ice.candidate.candidate.split('\r\n').find(function (line) {   
    if (line.indexOf("candidate")!==-1) {           
      var parts = line.split(' ');
      var type = parts[7];
      return type === 'host'
    }
  });
  pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  return line.split(' ')[4]
};
```

Something like this I think should work for .find.
.find will return the item, which you can then pull the addr from. Alternatively you could `let addr` outside, update that inside, then ignore the return value from .find.
Oh, you'll want to add something if your .find returns nothing, or things will break when you try to split it and pull something out.

Comment: Exactly this is what I am looking after. I just want to return just only one value which is the first address. Any example of using `.find` to return the first address, please?

Comment: Added to the answer. I _think_ that should work for a .find.

Comment: No problem. Using WebRTC sounds like a really interesting project. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your code in synchronous, you can write variables outside of the immediate function scope like so:

```js
let result = null;
ice.candidate.candidate.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {   
    if (line.indexOf("candidate")!==-1) {           
      var parts = line.split(' '),             
      addr = parts[4],
      type = parts[7];
      if (type === 'host') {
        console.log(addr);
        // Save value
        result = addr;
      }
    } 
  });
// ...
console.log(result);
```

This can be further improved by using a `for (let .. of ..)` loop and `break` to stop the loop after finding the value you're looking for.

You should also consider `Array.prototype.find()` for this.

Comment: instead of `console.log(result);` shall i get `return(result)` in another function?

Comment: You can `return result` in any scope below the declaration. Is that what you mean?